# Two Children to execute ls -la | grep using pipes

Tags: c, pipe, fork, exec, ls

Hey there i have a Problem understanding where this Code Fails. 
It probably Fails where execvpe(grep) is executed(Console: "Grep Error").

Heres the Code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   printf("filter.c\n");

   int fd[2];
   pid_t ls,grep;


   if(argc<3){
    printf("Bitte 2 Argumente angeben <Verzeichnis> <Suchmuster>");     
    exit(-1);
   }

   char verzeichnis[256];
   char suchmuster [256];
   char kind       [256];

   strcpy(verzeichnis,argv[1]);
   strcpy(suchmuster ,argv[2]);

   if(pipe(fd)<0){
       printf("Pipe fehlgeschlagen\n");
       return -1;
   }

   if((ls=fork())==-1){
    //fehler
    printf("Fork ls fehlgeschlagen\n");
    exit(-1);
   } else if(ls==0){
    //kind
    printf("\nChild1 laueft(ls)\n");
    if(dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)==-1){//dupliziert fd[1]
        printf("Dup failed(ls)\n");
        return -1;
    }

       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);


       char *argu[]={"-la",verzeichnis,NULL};
       if(execvpe("bin/ls",argu,NULL)==-1){//EXECVE
           printf("ls error");
           return -1;
       }
       return -1    }

   if((grep=fork())==-1){
       //fehler
       printf("Forken von grep fehlgeschlagen\n");
       return -1;
   } else if(grep==0){
       //children2
       printf("Child 2 lauft (grep)\n");
       if(dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO)==-1){
           printf("dup2 fd[0] fehlgeschlagen\n");
           return -1;
       }
       close(fd[0]);
       close(fd[1]);


       char *argu[]={"bin/grep",suchmuster,NULL};       
       if(execvpe("bin/grep",argu,NULL)==-1){
           printf("Grep error");
           return -1;
       }
       return -1;
   }
   close(fd[0]);
   close(fd[1]);

   while(wait(NULL)>0);//while()
   return 0;


   //   exit(0);
   }
```

So i guess there is a Problem writing and or reading to/from the pipe. Does anyone know my Problem? :/

Comment: A key piece of information in determining *where* your code fails would be *how* it fails.  What exactly is the nature of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: it Returns "Grep error", so it has to be there..

Comment: Unless you run your program from / directory, you should add proper path to grep. Try `"/bin/grep"`

Comment: Please improve your indentation. The code is hard to read.

Comment: @Gerhardh /bin/grep doesnt fix the Problem i tried this and other Things before.

Comment: It's generally useful to use `perror()` to print an error message describing the nature of the error.  Instead of just printing a generic error message as you do.

Comment: Thats a good piont. The error is "No such file or Directory im using "/home" as first Argument and "x" as second

Comment: i figuered out that sometimes grep first run and the ls.

Comment: I've rolled back your recent edits that destroyed the question. If you want to delete the question, there should be a "delete" link below the body of the question. If it's not there, or if it doesn't work, flag the question for moderator attention. But please consider whether you should delete it. This question has an accepted and upvoted answer, and it might be useful to future readers (which, frankly, is more important than solving your problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the given path to the executable contains a `/` character then no search is performed.  In that case the given path is resolved, if necessary, relative to the process's current working directory at the time of the call.  That is rarely what one wants, and your case does not look like an exception.  Morevover, if indeed you're going to specify a path to the binary instead of a simple name, then you get no advantage whatever from the path-searching variants of exec.

Furthermore, the last argument to `execvpe()` is supposed to be a pointer to the first element of a NULL-terminated array of `char *`.  Although the pointed-to array might have no elements other than the terminator, I find no documentation that the argument itself is permitted to be `NULL`. If you indeed want to specify empty environments for the exec'ed programs, then, both `execvpe()` calls should take this general form:

```
char *argu[] = { "grep", suchmuster, NULL };      
char *env[] = { NULL };
if (execvpe("/bin/grep", argu, env) == -1) {
```

Furthermore, execing the external processes with empty environments is suspect, though not necessarily wrong.  For this purpose I don't see much advantage, and you could save yourself some trouble by using one of the exec functions that just provides a copy of the calling process's environment to the exec'ed image.  `execvp()`, for example, would be the one closest to `execvpe()` that has that characteristic.

Moreover, it seems a bit silly to pack up the program arguments into an array that you use *only* for the exec call.  The varargs variants of exec circumvent any need to do that (`execl()`, etc.).

The exec functions return only on error.  You *can* test the return value, but if these functions return at all then their return values are always -1.

Taking all that into account, therefore, and supposing that it would be ok to give `grep` and `ls` copies of the parent process's environment, this is the general form I would suggest for your exec calls:

```
       execl("/bin/grep", "grep", suchmuster, NULL);
       // an error occurred
       perror("execing grep");
       _Exit(1);
```

Comment: If im executing
execl("bin/ls","-la",Verzeichnis,NULL);
perror();

Then it Exits there(No such file or directory). Ive tried "/home" "home" "." and "..". Am im inserting a wrong Argument? There are no subfolder in the current working directory

Comment: @Felix, you give a path containing a `/` but not starting with one.  It will be resolved relative to the current working directory, as I already explained, with no lookup in the path.  If, for example, the working directory is `/home/felix`, then the exec will look for `/home/felix/bin/ls`, and *only* for that.  Follow the model I presented.